# Symfony 4 : DRY and performant way to render OneToMany relation entities in same twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4, doctrine-query

I need to render some properties of two relational entities *Salarie* and *Contrat*, in a same twig template, basically from all the *Salarie* records but **only from one specific** *Contrat* **attached to each Salarie**.

**Salarie Entity**

```
namespace App\Entity;

class Salarie
{
// ...

/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contrat", mappedBy="salarie")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"dateDebut" = "DESC"})
     */
    private $contrats;
//...
```

**Contrat Entity**

```
namespace App\Entity;

class Contrat
{
// ...
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Salarie", inversedBy="contrats")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $salarie;
// ...
```

**Salarie controller**

```
class SalarieController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="salarie_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(SalarieRepository $salarieRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('salarie/index.html.twig', [
            'salaries' => $salarieRepository->findAll(), //findAllWithLastContrat(),
        ]);
    }
```

At first glance I thought this would be straightforward with **a custom query in Salarie repository**, but I've been fighting with joins, subqueries, and other stuff. Here's a *pure Twig working* solution , but it is **not DRY** at all, since I have to repeat it for each property , and I bet it has also a **performance hit** because I'm querying all the Contrat when I need only some...

```
<tbody class="list">
    {% for salarie in salaries %}
        <tr>
            <td>{% for contrat in salarie.contrats  %}
                  {% if loop.first %}
                    {{ contrat.departement }}
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>{% for contrat in salarie.contrats  %}
                  {% if loop.first %}
                    {{ contrat.service }}
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %} 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- AND SO ON ABOUT 12 TIMES ! -->
    {% endfor %}
```

### EDITED with @msg suggestions

I also tried a cool Feature from Doctrine ([Criteria](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/index.html#matching)) as explained in [Criteria System: Champion Collection Filtering](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/criteria-collection-filtering)

```
public function getLastContrat()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
      ->orderBy(['dateDebut' => 'DESC']);
      ->setMaxResults(1);

    return $this->contrats->matching($criteria)->current();
}
```

then in Twig  I can  `{{ dump(salarie.lastContrat) }}` returns the expected object.

[image]

But no way to get the properties from there.  `{{ salarie.lastContrat.someProperty }}` does not work.

[image: salarie.lastContrat.someProperty]

Has to see with the fact that `{{ salarie.lastContrat }}` prints what Contrat __toString method returns.

I won't expose more tries, so please my question is : **How to render the properties values from above `getLastContrat()` and what should be the most DRY and performant way to achieve this ?**

Comment: How does it not work? It should. Can you share the error you get ? Are the getters public?

Comment: @msg I posted the error. Yep getters are public.

Comment: Well, yeah `{{ salarie.lastContrat }}` is now an entity so it calls `__toString` since twig doesn't know how to render entities. You could define a `block` or `macro` to render it, but this is an entirely different question now.Maybe have a look at [`Sonata`](https://sonata-project.org/), for inspiration it has a twig extension. For the `id` issue, try `{% set %}` first, calling the function each time you access a property is not the most DRY, and most likely that's why the result hasn't been hydrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping, you just can extract the first element:

```
{% if not empty salarie.contrats %}
    {% set contrat = salarie.contrats[0] %}
    {# you can also use salarie.contrats|first #}
    {{ contrat.departement }}
{% endif %}
```

`Criteria` returns a `Collection` even if there's just one element, so you can apply the same principle as above.

Although you could also extract the results in your controller before passing them to twig and pass them as Entities instead of collections. In your repository above:

```
/**
 * @returns Contrat|null
 */
public function getLastContrat()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
      ->orderBy(['dateDebut' => 'DESC'])
      ->setMaxResults(1);

    return $this->contrats->matching($criteria)->first();
}
```

Comment: Great!  I'll give it a try tomorrow  :-) .  I knew about first  in Twig but could not chain `salarie.contrats.first.someProperty` .... maybe it has to be done in 2 steps as you did, passing to a variable first.

Comment: @Kojo If you want to chain you could try with array access `...[0].prop` but then you are going to repeat that ugly thing for each property. Also made a couple of changes to the repository function that I didn't catch before. Hope it works!

Comment: Well, none works. salarie.contrats|first returns the __toString metod, so no way to get the properties from it. And matching($criteria)->first() or current returns the correct object, but I can't find the way to get the properties from there, either chaining methods or with Twig . I will edit the question. Thanks

Comment: My bad, @msg you're right I got confused sorry ! In fact the key is it works if you set a variable first : both `{% set lastContrat = salarie.lastContrat %}` and                         `{% set last = salarie.contrats|first %}` work, I just have to render then `{{ last.someContratProperty }}` ; thanks for your patience ;-)

Comment: @Kojo No problem. I searched for the code I mentioned, [here's how they do it](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/855118ffc22518ee4db04dd20714519e33675ae1/src/Resources/views/CRUD/Association/list_one_to_many.html.twig#L34) and the [Twig extension](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/24e2b460e80f075629facb1dfc317117400f3d00/src/Twig/Extension/SonataAdminExtension.php#L340). This is Sonata specific, although given your last update I'm quite certain you could do with `macros` or `includes`, I'll try to expand my answer later.

Answer (score 1):

another thing you can do is to pass into the template another variable with the related object that you want to render (last contrat in your case). So, in your controller, you first fetch the Salarie object and then fetch the desired contrat. It's not the most DRY solution but you can't really apply DRY if you don't have more use cases where you need/want to re-use a piece of code. So, this approach is good because you don't need any criteria logic on your entity and it's very performant because you only fetch what you need.

If you don't have more use cases that may re-use the code, then don't over-optimize, wait for the situation to occur, and then you can look for a way to share your code, based on real needs, not in believings :)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I'm afraid I can't do this because in the template I render all `Salarie`, not a single one, so I believe I'm obliged to wrap last `Contrat` within the variable : `salaries`; I added the controller to my question to make it clear. I understand what you mean about DRY, I asked this because I have to repeat the `for/if` loop many times and it makes my template quite ugly ;-) . And ...my bad, I just realized that @msg 's answer is correct!!! What I misunderstand is why I have to pass to a variable first in Twig instead of chaining